# VBScript to create an outlook rule

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook

I'm trying to create a `vbscript` that I can distribute so an outlook rule is created for each user that runs it.

I have some code (below), however I have since found I can't create a rule via `VBS` with Actions.Run ("VBA Code"). I need a rule so that whenever an email is received from `"test@test.com"` a `msgbox` is displayed that the user must click OK an.

Through my research it indicates that the VBA may somehow be able to be implemented in the `VBS` file, but I can't find much on it.

The VBA I want to run is:

```
Sub newmsg(item As Outlook.MailItem)
 MsgBox "You have an urgent message: " & item.Subject
End Sub
```

and the VBS is:

```
'--> Create some constants
Const RULE_NAME = "Urgent Message"  '<-- Edit the name of the rule
Const olRuleReceive = 0

'--> Create some variables
Dim olkApp, olkSes, olkCol, olkRul, olkCon, olkAct

'--> Connect to Outlook
Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olkSes = olkApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
olkSes.Logon olkApp.DefaultProfileName

'--> Get the rules collection
Set olkCol = olkSes.DefaultStore.GetRules()

'--> Create a new receive rule
Set olkRul = olkCol.Create(RULE_NAME, olRuleReceive)

'--> Set the rule's condition to look for a specific word in the subject
Set olkCon = olkRul.Conditions.From
With olkCon
    .Enabled = True
    .Recipients.Add ("email address here")
    .Recipients.ResolveAll
End With


'--> Set the rule's action
Set olkAct = olkRul.Actions.Run("Project1.newmsg")
With olkAct
    .Enabled = True
End With

'--> Save the rule
olkCol.Save False

'--> Disconnect from Outlook
olkSes.Logoff
Set olkCon = Nothing
Set olkAct = Nothing
Set olkRul = Nothing
Set olkCol = Nothing
Set olkSes = Nothing
Set olkApp = Nothing

'--> Terminate the script
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Are you expecting the newmsg method to exist or are you hoping to create that method using VBS?

Comment: Hi Eric, Hoping to create that method using VBS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only supported way to modify VBA projects is by developing an add-in for the VBA editor using the [Visual Basic Extensibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443984(v=vs.60).aspx) interfaces.

If you need to create a rule that performs a custom action then I recommend you build an Outlook add-in that processes incoming email messages and does the action within your add-in's code, rather than relying on a VBA method that may or may not exist.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I'll start looking into creating an Outlook Add-In